# split string into multiple lists by a char

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I have a returned string from a function such:

```
"& True  True & True  False & False"
```

I need to write a function that puts all the elements between `&` in a list and deletes it, such:

```
[[True, True], [True, False], [False]]
```

How do I do it?
thanks in advance!

Comment: `results = mystring.split("&")` would be a good start.

Comment: Then for each of the elements of that list you can use `split()` to split it at whitespace. Then loop over those strings and replace `"True"` with `True` and `"False"` with `False`

Comment: Since there are already a lot of answers: `[list(map(lambda s: s=='True', entry.split())) for entry in value.split('&') if entry]`

Answer (score 2):

you can use split

```
 l = "& True  True & True  False & False"
 result = [j.split() for j in l.split('&') if j!='']
 print(result)
```

output

```
[['True', 'True'], ['True', 'False'], ['False']]
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex:

```
import re
s = "& True  True & True  False & False"
out = [list(map(eval, i.split())) for i in re.findall("&?([^&]+)&?", s)]
```

gives

```
[[True, True], [True, False], [False]]
```

As it is known, `eval` is dangerous so if you actually want the boolean values, use `ast.literal_eval` in place of `eval` as the safest choice, or you can have a dirty lambda inside like this:

```
[list(map(lambda x: x == 'True', i.split())) for i in re.findall("&?([^&]+)&?", s)]
```

Comment: `eval`? Really?

Comment: Didn't feel like adding `ast.literal_eval` for fixed strings.

Comment: Let's just mention that `eval` should never be used with untrusted data. If this string is fixed the answer would be `print([[True, True], [True, False], [False]])` ;)

Answer (score 1):

and dont forget to cast it to bool:

```
mystr = "& True  True & True  False & False"
l = [[s == 'True' for s in t.strip().split()] for t in mystr.strip('&').split('&')]
>>> l
[[True, True], [True, False], [False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method of string

> yourstring.split("&")

see this , it can be helpfull for you .

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with `filter`, `map` and `split`,

```
string = '& True True & True False & False'
required = list(filter(None,map(str.strip, string.split('&'))))
result = [l.split() for l in required]
print(result)
```

**Result:**

```
[['True', 'True'], ['True', 'False'], ['False']]
```

Comment: isn't this over-engineered?

Comment: Also, you don't need to convert the `map` object to `list`, direct filter over map would work just fine: `list(filter(None, map(str.strip, s.split('&'))))`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes, because I like over engineering :P. Thanks for pointing out